# Vimeo Channels Search

Tags: api, search, vimeo, media-channel

Vimeo Advanced API has a method channels.getAll which returns all public channels.

Is there any method which returns the channels for a search key word.

Eg. Channels for search keyword 'abc' should return these results:
http://vimeo.com/search/channels/search:abc/st/90fe603a

Answer (score 1):

No there is no any method in vimeo api that search the channels for specified keyword For more information please go https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods#